# Google Chrome Extension - Programmatically Open Popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When you make a Google Chrome Extension you can choose to have a "Default_Popup", is there any way to programmatically open the popup?

Comment: I think you'll soon be able to assign a keyboard shortcut to do that, but allowing scripts to do so whenever they like would probably be a bad user experience.

Comment: In some cases I agree, but for what the user has suggested, it works in their favor. Not randomly doing it, it's a setting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct way to open the popup programmatically. However, if you're looking to open it based on a keyboard shortcut, you can use the [commands API](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/commands.html) with the `_execute_browser_action` command (the API is currently available on the beta channel only).

Comment: Thank you, although I never got around to using this, it's a good answer, sorry I took so long to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is an API, chrome.browserAction.openPopup(function callback), that will hopefully be available soon. Please star this bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436489

Comment: Note: the discussion about enabling this API became complex; there's no indication when this happens. Not "soon".

Comment: For the record, this is available in Firefox 57+ but not yet publicly available in Chrome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/openPopup