# Chrome extension popup showing by condition

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup

I want to show popup by click, but only if condition is false.
After click to extension icon background js searchig for tab with current name. If tab found background js continues working. If not found - i want to show popup with instructions. Can`t understand how to just show popup in this case.
I can set popup by browserAction.setPopup(), but popup will be displayed only after next clicks.
I just want to show my popup one time.
It is definitely posible, I've seen this behavior on other extension.

```
var pcTabs; // tabs array

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClick);

function buttonClick() {
 // getting tabs...
 if(pcTabs.length != 0){
    // working with finded tabs
 } else{ // tabs not found
    // show popup.html here. this is the question
 }
}
```

**upd**.
This is my [background.js](https://github.com/illuzor/Play-Button-For-Pocket-Casts/blob/master/source/background.js). All code also in repository.
How to replace alerts to popups?

Comment: Can you please edit your question the missing commas are messing me, up(not trying to be a di*k.

and "I want to show popup by click" click on current page or on the browser action

Comment: where is this js file in the background file or the popup? and also you don't need to put `!= 01 because in javascript `1 == true` and `0 == false`

Comment: In the background. Thanks for explanation about true/false

Comment: ok so what you want is:

when you click on the browserAction, you want to find certain tabs

if you found them don't show the popup if you do then show it?

Comment: Yes. For example [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play/ocimhajpehjmepnegklahceceebnened) extenstion. If google music page is not opened, displaying popup with links. If opened - just paused\playing music. I want to implement exactly the same behavior

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short: you can't do it the way you describe.

When a popup page is set, `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` won't fire, and the popup will show.

When a popup page is not set, your event listener will execute, but you [cannot show a popup programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868386/google-chrome-extension-programmatically-open-popup). The most you can do is to *set* a popup for the next click.

So, what to do with it?

1) You can do an ugly hack (kind of) described in Edwin's answer. Always show the popup, check the condition as soon as possible, message the background and execute `window.close()` if the condition is met.

Of course, it is ugly.

2) **The proper way to do this** would be updating the popup whenever the condition can potentially change. That is, whenever you add/remove data from `pcTabs`, you should set/unset the popup with [`chrome.browserAction.setPopup`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setPopup)

```
// ... somewhere ...
pcTabs.push(/*...*/);
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: ''});

// ... somewhere else ...
pcTabs.pop(/*...*/);
if(!pcTabs.length) chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: 'popup.html'});    

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  // Assume condition is met, popup didn't show
});
```

3) The ***fancy*** way to do it is to use experimental JavaScript method, [`Array.observe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe), that is only supported in Chrome.

```
var pcTabs = [];
Array.observe(pcTabs, function(changes) {
  changes.forEach(function(change) {
    if(change.object.length) {
      chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: ''});
    }   else {
      chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: 'popup.html'});  
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for information. Second way looks nice. I can set listeners to chrome.tabs(open/close/update). But would it be good idea? All tabs will be checked many times, mostly absolutely unnecessary. I`m thinking it would be ok, if I leave alerts. If somebody using this extension, he know why he doing it and will not click button without the need.

Comment: You could also use `chrome.notifications` in a less obtrusive way than alerts, or use the second/third methods to enable/disable the button instead of setting the popup.

Comment: There is an API to show the popup programmatically, but it is whitelisted :( https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=305744

Answer (score -1):

Alright this is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
    if (!tabs[0].url.includes('google.com')) { //check if current tab is not google: if false show popup, you can just put an else at the end and do w.e with your popup
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, url: 'https://*.google.com/*'}, function(tabs) { //since current tab is not google query tabs with google
            if (tabs.length) { //check if there are any pages with google
                chrome.tabs.highlight({tabs: tabs[0].index}, function(w) {}); //this is what I chose to do idk what you want to do but you can write w.e here
            } else { 
                chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://google.com'}); //other wise no pages with google open one
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: And this is an answer to this question _how?_

Comment: isn't that what he wants to do but different functions meaning not open a new page but something else which he can write w.e he want there, like not change the current tab(highlighting) but something else I'm not sure what is it that he wants to do

Comment: As a matter of principle, it's best to ask before answering if you're unsure. The question title is pretty clear though: how to open a (browser action) popup or not depending on a condition.

Comment: that's the condition right there `if(!tabs[0].url.includes('google.com')`

Comment: And how does that [show a popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)?

Comment: to show a popup that if statement has to be false and it will continue running. That code is in the **popup.js** file

so because it's not telling any tab to switch to or open a new one it keeps the popup open. when the statment is true

and switches to the google tab or create another one it's closing the popup

Comment: Aha. Now that makes more sense. You should probably merge your two answers into one, including this information.. Also, `highlight` doesn't do what you expect it to do. You probably want to do `tabs.update` with `{active: true}`.

Comment: for me highlight worked. It switches to the tab that is on google already instead of making a new one. if there is not tab with google then create a new one

Comment: I think that the opening of the missing tab is a good idea in my case