# Can a chrome extension be opened when requesting specific external protocol?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, network-protocols

I want to write a chrome extension that is triggered when the browser redirect to a specific external protocol: `myApp://...`

I googled a bit and didn't find an easy meta-data way to do so.

is there a way to define it in the manifest?

I want the extension to open a popup then, and I'll wait for it in my automation testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, in theory, use a [protocol handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers) with [`navigator.registerProtocolHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/navigator.registerProtocolHandler), but there are limitations:

- Custom protocols *must* start with `web+` in Chrome, e.g. `web+myApp:`
- There is no way to declare this in a manifest; according to [this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86115) to add that possibility, currently it will pop up an allow/deny infobar for the user.

In any case, [opening a popup programmatically is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12868386/934239). At most you can open an extension page in a tab.

Comment: how about FF? `Custom protocols must start with web+`?  and `There is no way to declare this in a manifest` ? how can I write such addon?

Comment: That would be a different question that I can't answer, it's outside my expertise.