# Opening Chrome Extension using platform API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my extension popup window, I have a button that opens a new window and loads a set of tabs. This works as expected.

Now I'd like to have my extension re-open when the new window is created. Maybe something like...

```
chrome.windows.create({ url: ["some", "array"] }, function() {
    chrome.extension.openCurrent(); // this doesn't exist
});
```

Something like that... so I can persist my extension in the new window. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Extension - Programmatically Open Popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868386/google-chrome-extension-programmatically-open-popup)

Comment: Thanks, that's close, but I don't want to use keyboard shortcut. That's mess with the experience. I think my only other option is to get all current tabs, remove them and open in a new unfocused window then open the tabs that I intend to. I think the popup should remain open in that case. Maybe.

Comment: You should not rely on popup being open. It's too fragile (focus lost -> closed) and you _can't_ open it again, that's my point. But you're probably right: creating a window that's not focused, if possible with the API, should probably keep the popup open.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API, chrome.browserAction.openPopup(function callback), that will hopefully be available soon. Please star this bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436489

Comment: Oh _wow_, you convinced kalman on that. You should add this answer to the question I linked as a canonical duplicate though.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Starred it and will keep an eye on it.