# Trigger chrome extension browser action popup on mouse over of email like connect6 extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to replicate the connect6 chrome extension for my application.
All I want to do is trigger the browser action pop up on mouse over.
Please tell how to programmatically trigger the browser action pop up and where to specify the code.Content.js or background.js

Comment: Zero effort "give me teh codez" questions are not welcome on Stack Overflow. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You [can't open the broswer action programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868386/google-chrome-extension-programmatically-open-popup).

Besides, that's not what that extension is doing: it's showing its UI inside the page. That has to be handled by the content script.