# Activate popup.html from Content Script: Chrome Extension Development

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My current project requires opening/activating popup.html (browserAction) from content script? I have read a few answers that say, it's not possible because of security concern.

E.g Ans: [How can I open my extension's pop-up with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479679/how-can-i-open-my-extensions-pop-up-with-javascript)

If that's the case, then how Chrome Bookmark Manager extension does it when CTRL+D shortcut is pressed?

Ref: [Bookmark Manager Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager/gmlllbghnfkpflemihljekbapjopfjik?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Comment: Google's extensions are often whitelisted in the source code of chrome and thus can do more stuff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868386/google-chrome-extension-programmatically-open-popup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're just using the [commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) interface, with an event name of `_execute_page_action` (or `_execute_browser_action`). They've set the default shortcut to `Ctrl+D`.

Activating this command will perform a click on the page (or browser) action, opening the popup or whatever the action is configured to do.

Chrome only respects the default shortcut key if it does not conflict with built-in commands, but it makes an exception for extensions that specify `chrome_ui_overrides.bookmarks_ui` [[1]](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/_manifest_features.json?type=cs&q=D5736E4B5CF695CB93A2FB57E4FDC6E5AFAB6FE2+f:manifest_features.json&l=61), which is currently restricted to the dev channel or the experimental extension by Google.

The Cast extension used to programmatically open its popup, which is the only one I've seen. The API is similarly whitelisted: [browserAction.openPopup](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/_manifest_features.json?type=cs&q=D5736E4B5CF695CB93A2FB57E4FDC6E5AFAB6FE2+f:manifest_features.json&l=61).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction/setPopup

Looks like they are using this.

```
       a.h.get(c).then(function(a) {
        var c = chrome.pageAction;
        a ? (c.setTitle({
            tabId: b,
            title: Ga
        }),
        c.setIcon({
            tabId: b,
            imageData: {
                19: Cc,
                38: Dc
            }
        })) : (c.setTitle({
            tabId: b,
            title: Ha
        }),
        c.setIcon({
            tabId: b,
            imageData: {
                19: Ec,
                38: Fc
            }
        }));
        c.setPopup({
            tabId: b,
            popup: "popup.html"
        });
        c.show(b)
    })
};
```

Looking at background_compiled.js

This looks supported but I have not tested. This me briefly looking at the code and just running a search for popup.html. But this might be what you are looking for.