# how to open tronlink wallet from chrome browser programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, tron

I have installed [tron link wallet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tronlink%EF%BC%88%E6%B3%A2%E5%AE%9D%E9%92%B1%E5%8C%85%EF%BC%89/ibnejdfjmmkpcnlpebklmnkoeoihofec) extenstions in google chrome browser. I have a web application. I need to open this tron wallet from browser to do transaction. I do not need to open tronlink extension in pop-up window. It is OK if it is opening in either new tab or in the same tab. This question might be duplicate of [How can I open my extension's pop-up with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479679/how-can-i-open-my-extensions-pop-up-with-javascript) or [Activate popup.html from Content Script: Chrome Extension Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923097/activate-popup-html-from-content-script-chrome-extension-development). But I am not getting clear answer there. My question is, Is it possible to open tronlink wallet from chrome browser by a click ? If we can, how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a web application that need do Tron transaction (called DAPP) you can use Tron web API ( in javascript ) :

`tronWeb.transactionBuilder.sendTrx(to, amount, from, options);`

[Full API reference](https://developers.tron.network/reference#sendtrx)